# Create multiple java classes from an eclipse template in one go

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse has features for templates that make repetitive coding (with slight variations) more easy and efficient.

I often find myself making a template like this:

- XXXView
- XXXViewInterface
- XXXViewListener
- XXXViewPresenter

As per the MVP pattern https://vaadin.com/web/magi/home/-/blogs/model-view-presenter-pattern-with-vaadin

Those classes then interact and reference eachother, but always in the same way.

My question is: Could I define these 4 classes as a template, so all I have to do is type in "XXX" and generate the four java classes from that

Comment: @AleksandrM it's relatively simple to make smug comments.

Comment: @mhvelplund Better than a smug answers. ;) Do you know how to do this in eclipse, besides creating a plugin?

Comment: @AleksandrM no smug answer is complete without a 5 second Google search link, e.g.: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html or http://www.wideskills.com/eclipse-plugin-tutorial

To be clear though; I agree that this is something that would be doable as a plugin by following the steps in the tutorials.

Comment: @mhvelplund What? OP asks for creating a multiple classes at once. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @mhvelplund My comment was the sign that it can be done, but it isn't included out of the box.

Comment: @mhvelplund Good solution. If that suits OP needs then it is the simplest way to go.

Comment: I am not sure, but i think you can use Spring Roo for this - http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple classes inside another class as static inner classes. That would work fine with Eclipse templates. But a cleaner solution might be to write a plugin for it, as suggested by @AleksandrM above.